# What is the style of the bas-reliefs in these photos?

Tags: style-identification

I recently became interested in interior design, and I would like to apply the classic style that can be seen in the images below from the movie "House of Gucci".

As far as I've been able to research it, I found out that the style of the bas-reliefs is Greek or Roman, but I cannot find the exact house where this scene was shot, or any other apartments with the same design style.

Can you identify for me the culture/style of these bas-reliefs?  It would also be great if someone happened to know the name of the house where the scene was shot.

[image]

I'm especially interested in these details:

[image] [image]

Comment: Hi, there are a few problems with your questions: "where can I find" is asking for resources, and off-topic, plus your reference photos are of very poor quality (I can imagine one would be able to find better photos of this scene online, and it's also a strange starting point for interior design :), plus you've picked out two styles to identify, while it's better to focus your question on one particular 'problem'. I think these could be reasons you got downvoted. Nevertheless, ultimately you're asking for style identification, which is on-topic here.

Comment: Tk you Joachim for your comments which are very helpful because I really want to make my question better so that it can be answered. Despite that I have spent a good time to find the info to ask my question but the info I can find is too little. There is only one image I could have so that the quality of the photo is so poor. I also don't know where is a good place to put this question if you can point me to somewhere I can put this topic would be much appreciated ! Thank you !

Comment: The issue readers were having, even with Joachim's edit, is that interior styling (the entire space as art), is off-topic.  The site focuses on "handmade, tangible works".  So the individual bas-reliefs, or the collection of similar individual works, can be on-topic, but readers had to make that leap in interpretation.  I did a little wordsmithing to make that focus explicit.

Comment: @fixer1234 Which is something worth bringing up, because where does an artwork end and an interior begin? There are completely preserved rooms in museum around the world. And even so, this might broaden our scope while remaining perfectly answerable within the SE network Q&A format restrictions.

Comment: @Joachim, my thoughts, exactly.

Answer (score 2):

The scene in *House of Gucci* you're referring to was filmed in **Villa Polissena**, in Rome. It was built in the 1920s.

The hefty decorative character of the niches with the busts and the central bas-reliefs seem a tad too opulent for it, but overall this particular room breathes **neoclassicism**: the rigid delineations and symmetry, the sober palette of subdued pastels ('*[en camaïeu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cama%C3%AFeu)*'), the classical style of the reliefs and decorations, the (pedimented) window frames, and the subdivision of the walls all point to it.

I found a few higher-quality images of the interior seen in this scene from *House of Gucci*:

| [image] | [image] |
| --- | --- |
| <sup>[source](https://blog.hola.com/allabouteu/2015/12/villa-polissena.html)</sup> | <sup>[source](https://artmaki.de/albums/villa-polissena-rome/)</sup> |

Since neoclassicism imitated the ancient Roman style in all its aspects, the bas-reliefs, with their rigid theatrical figures and composition and classical motifs, are probably neoclassical as well.

| [image] | [image] | [image] |
| --- | --- | --- |
| <sup>[source](https://www.gosee.news/news/celebrity/a-visit-with-mafalda-princess-of-hesse-and-rolf-sachs-in-the-villa-polissena-for-salon-magazine-photos-by-wolfgang-stahr-c-o-nerger-m-o-57365/issue/1048)</sup> | <sup>[source](https://www.welt.de/iconist/unterwegs/article158396071/So-wohnt-die-Urururenkelin-von-Koenigin-Viktoria.html)</sup> | <sup>by [Wolfgang Stahr](https://artmaki.de/albums/villa-polissena-rome/)</sup> |